# Basic question about linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was solving this question, and encountered a very "basic" problem that I want to make sure if what I did was right:

Let $P:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $P\circ P=P , dimV=n$, Prove that $(I-P)\circ (I-P)=I-P$. 
At the ending stages I reached something that looked like this: 
$-P(I(v)-P(v))$ , and I did this explaining that I used the linearity : $-P(I(v)-P(v))=-P(I(v))+P(P(v))$. 
 
 And I checked everywhere for something about subtraction but everywhere I see the linearity property defined with $T(v+u)=T(v)+T(u)$, I wanted to ask if it applies for subtraction too just to make sure I am not missing something. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity also includes scalar multiplication: $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v).$ In particular, then, $$T(v-u)=T\bigl(v+(-1)u\bigr)=T(v)+T\bigl((-1)u)=T(v)+(-1)T(u)=T(v)-T(u).$$

As for your figuring, it seems something may have gone wrong: $$(I-P)\circ(I-P)=I(I-P)-P(I-P)=I-P-\bigl(P(I)-P(P)\bigr)=I-P-(P-P)=I-P.$$

Comment: Appreciate the clear explanation, I got it right just didn't bother copying the whole thing since I wanted to make sure about the subtraction, thanks alot!

Comment: No problem! Just wanted to make sure. :-)

Comment: Appreciate it :), sorry if I'm digging again probably would be better to ask a new question if it's too long, but I was asked to prove that $kerP=Im(I-P)$, and $ker(I-P)=ImP$. I started proving that $kerP\subset Im(I-P)$, and done it successfully, but I'm stuck on the other direction, if you could help I will be thankful.

Comment: The other direction is pretty straightforward. Suppose $v$ is in the image of $I-P,$ meaning that  $v=(I-P)(u)$ for some $u\in V.$ But as we saw in the calculation above, $P(I-P)=P-P=0,$ so $P(v)=0,$ and so $v$ is in the kernel of $P.$

Comment: Thankss, this really clears it, just to make sure you applied $P$ to both sides of the equation $v=(I-P)(u)$ and got that $P(v)=P((I-P)(u))=P(I(u)-P(u))=P(u)-P(u)=0$

Comment: That's correct, but it's actually simpler, since $$P\bigl((I-P)(u)\bigr)=\bigl(P(I-P)\bigr)(u)=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Sure. After all,\begin{align}T(u-v)+T(v)&=T\bigl((u-v)+v\bigr)\\&=T(u)\end{align}and therefore$$T(u-v)=T(u)-T(v).$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply linearity several times.

\begin{align}
&-P(I(v)-P(v))
\\
&= -[P(I(v)) + P(-P(v))] &\text{since }P(u+w)=P(u)+P(w)
\\
&= -[P(I(v)) - P(P(v))] & \text{since } P(-u) = -P(u)
\\
&= -P(I(v)) + P(P(v)) & \text{since } -(u-w) = -u+w
\end{align}